# Selenium not utilizing "--print-to-pdf" option and printing to network printers

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm building a Selenium powered script that visits a set of websites and downloads them directly to a PDF.  While I'm on our office wifi, the Chromium browser defaults to a network printer it finds instead of the configured "pdf" setting I've set.

1. Add a custom set of prefs to point Chromium to the last used print settings (pdf).
2. Add Chrome arguments --kiosk-printing and --print-to-pdf
3. Switched to another wifi network without printers (this works with the arguments!)

I initialize the web driver using:

```py
def init_chromium():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--kiosk-printing")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--print-to-pdf")
    chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    return chrome_driver
```

I then iterate through a list of pages to visit and use the JS to print the page with a special "label" the user provides.

```py
def page_navigation (driver, page_array, label):
    for i in page_array:
        print("Getting page {}".format(i))
        driver.get(i)
        driver.execute_script("document.title = '{}' + ' - ' + document.title".format(label))
        driver.execute_script("window.print();")
        print("Executed printing of {}.".format(i))
```

No error messages appear, but I need a way of overriding the printing configurations regardless of the network I'm on.  Changing wifi networks at the beginning/end of the script isn't ideal.

Comment: I think `--print-to-pdf` is only available if you are running in headless mode.

Comment: Good callout!  Sorry for not catching that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I noticed that Chrome would pick up printers located on my network and try to print to them whether or not I would have them configured - even if I supplied my own user configs. Since we have a "guest" network in the office, I decided to work around this by running two subprocesses before the scraper begins.

```py
def check_network_and_printers():
    current_network=subprocess.run(["/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport", "-I"], capture_output=True)
    if "BAD NETWORK SSID" in str(current_network):
        logging.error("ERROR: This computer is connected to the BAD NETWORK SSID network.  Please switch to another network before re-running this program.")
        exit()
    current_printers=subprocess.run(["lpstat", "-s"], capture_output=True)
    if "No destinations added" not in str(current_printers):
            logging.error("ERROR:  Please remove any configured printers from your MacBook before running this script!")
            exit()
```

Not the best solution, but if there are no printers configured then Chrome will default to the desired "Print to PDF" option.  Hopefully, this helps someone out in the future. :)